# Show group by data and auto dynamic dots at columns

Tags: javascript, php, html

What i want to create is a kind of quick reference telephone directory, where you see names and telephones grouped by Department.

So, i create a div with id=mycol, and in css i created the rule:

```
#mycol {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}
```

Then in php I create and fetch with while loop a query like:

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable GROUP BY Department ORDER BY Department, Lastname ASC"; ?>
```

and i echo the results like this:

```
<?php $html="<div id='mycol'>";
while ($row = $sth->fetch()) {
     $html .= "<p>" . $row['Lastname'] . ", ".$row['Firstname']."</p>";  
     $html .= "<p>" . $row['Telephone'] . "</p><br>";  
}
$html .= "</div>";
echo $html; ?>
```

How can i show the Department name on top of each grouped result?
For example:

```
HR
John, Doe....12345
George, Doe....456789

Finance
Catherine, Doe...45678941
etc
```

Also, how can i somehow have the dots between the 2 fields but to be dynamically created covering the space between First name/Last name and the telephone?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have to use a single query(and loop) for the solution? Cause you can use a query, get all department and then query the names for every department separately. It is passible to do this in a single one, but it won't be as nice of a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this shoud work, but keep in mind, it is an example on using nested loops for grouped data, not on sql statements. I used this quick-and-ditry way to illustrate the method of the solution.

```
<table><?php
    $query = "select distinct Department from mytable order by Department asc;";
    $result = $db->query($query);

    while($dep = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        ?><tr>
            <td colspan="2"><?php echo $dep['Department']; ?></td>
        </tr><?php

        $department = $dep['Department'];
        $query = "select * from mytable where Department = $department order by Lastname asc, Firstname asc;";
        $res = $db->query($query);

        while($user = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?><tr>
                <td><?php echo $user['Lastname'] . ', ' . $user['Firstname']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $dep['Phone']; ?></td>
            </tr><?php

        }

    }

?><table>
```

**UPDATE:** As of the dotted fillings, I found the following solution using `display:flex;` On these example rows:

```
<p><span class="name">Name</span><span class="dotted"></span><span class="number">12345689</span></p>
<p><span class="name">Someone Name</span><span class="dotted"></span><span class="number">43633</span></p>
<p><span class="name">My Name</span><span class="dotted"></span><span class="number">5677</span></p>
<p><span class="name">Joe</span><span class="dotted"></span><span class="number">12345623289</span></p>
```

With a CSS:

```
p {display:flex; width: 500px; height: 14px; margin: 1px;}
p span.name {display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; float: left;}
p span.number {display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; float: right;}
p span.dotted {display: inline-block; width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px dotted black;}
```

And here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4gdxpzq/) with the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea. I did your idea (loop inside a loop) and i get what i need. But, do you have any idea of how to fill in dots between Last/Firstname and telephone (like quick reference telephone guides)?

Comment: @PanBou Well, if you use a monospace font, you can use a [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function with a big enough length like: `str_pad($user['Lastname'] . ', ' . $user['Firstname'], 100, '.', STR_PAD_RIGHT)`. But I have no clue how to achieve this with css, sorry.

Comment: @PanBou But in my opinion, a table with alternating row striping is looks just as fine. :)

Comment: @PanBou I find a solution, and updated my answer accordingly.